# How to construct $\operatorname{End}(V_{\pi})$ using a representation $\pi$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $(\pi, V)$ be a representation of the group $G$. To make the setting as general as possible, I will not put any restrictions on $\pi, V$, and $G$ from the beginning.

By the very definition, for each $g\in G$, $\pi(g)\in \operatorname{GL}(V)$. I would like to use $\pi$ to construct *all* maps in $\operatorname{End}(V)$ (or rather $B(V)$ the set of bounded functions on $V$).

Clearly, $\pi(\phi)=\int_G\phi(g)\pi(g)\, dg$ is one such function in $\operatorname{End}(V)$ when $\phi\in L^1(G)$. However, in this generality we cannot necessarily generate all endomorphisms; for instance when $\pi=I_V$.

My question is

> > Under what conditions the equality $B(V)=\{\pi (\phi)\}$ holds?

Comment: It's clearly necessary for $V$ to be irreducible. On that note, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem.

Comment: I think this is a not-the-right-question, as $\pi(\phi)$ is always invertible. What you might want to ask is when $\operatorname{End} V$ is *spanned* (linearly or topologically-linearly) by maps of the form $\pi(\phi)$. This is where the Jacobson density theorem Qiaochu linked to comes into play.

Comment: @darijgrinberg $\pi(\phi)$ is not necessarily invertible. (eg take $\phi=0$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand that irreducibility is used in Jacobson's theorem, but it's not clear to me why for a reducible repn $B(V)\ne \{\pi(\phi)\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see: $\phi \in L^1\left(G\right)$, not in $G$.